# Parsing a table in jsoup (Android)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

http://www.novaprojecten.nl/roosters/lbl/basis/38/c/c00086.htm

i'm trying to parse the table seen there...

what i want is to put all the days (the first row) into a ListView.

When i tap the ListView item per day i want to show the data in the column below that day, including the time per classroom...

e.g. in one row: 12:45 - 15:15 LBL130 (ICT)

What is the best way to do this on android?

Comment: Have you tried anything, or were you just hoping for a code dump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is horrible HTML you are trying to parse. But you can select the days with JSoup using the correct selector. The complete selector is `table tbody tr td table tbody tr td font` but it can be shortened to `body > center > table > tbody > tr:lt(1) font`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.novaprojecten.nl/roosters/lbl/basis/38/c/c00086.htm").get();
List<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Element col: doc.select("body > center > table > tbody > tr:lt(1) font")) {
    days.add(col.text());
}
System.out.println(days); // Maandag 17-09, Dinsdag 18-09, Woensdag 19-09...
```

In order to select contents for each day you will have to parse each row and retrieve only the n-th column.

All this is possible using JSoup, to answer your question. You should take a look at [their website](http://jsoup.org) and at the [Selector documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), in order to try further things yourself.

Comment: @iSeeDeadPixels See my edit for the correct selector for days of the week.